# Mean over 2d numpy array with varying slices

Tags: performance, numpy, indexing, slice

I need to calculate the mean over the columns of a 2D numpy array where the slice per column varies.

For example, I have an array

```
    arr = np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)
```

with the end index of the slice for each column mean defined as

```
    bot_ix = np.array([3, 2, 2, 1, 2])
```

The mean of the first column would then be

```
    arr[0:bot_ix[0], 0].mean()
```

What's the appropriate (i.e. Pythonic + efficient) way to do this?  My array sizes are ~(50, 50K).

Comment: I selected the fastest time for the answer.  For comparison and posterity:
Divakar: 12.4 ms
Oliver: 47.5 ms
piRSquared: 18.4 ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
mask = bot_ix > np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:,None]
out = np.true_divide(np.einsum('ij,ij->j',arr,mask),mask.sum(0))
```

Sample run to verify results -

```
In [431]: arr
Out[431]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

In [432]: bot_ix
Out[432]: array([3, 2, 2, 1, 2])

In [433]: np.true_divide(np.einsum('ij,ij->j',arr,mask),mask.sum(0))
Out[433]: array([ 5. ,  3.5,  4.5,  3. ,  6.5])

In [434]: [arr[0:item, i].mean() for i,item in enumerate(bot_ix)]
Out[434]: [5.0, 3.5, 4.5, 3.0, 6.5] # Loopy version to test out o/p
```

Comment: You could go even one step more optimal by replacing the `mask.sum(0)` with simply `bot_ix`. But the best solution so far! +1

Comment: @OliverW. Ah of course! I missed that, thanks! OP should take a note of it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, would be to let numpy compute the cumulative sum and then use fancy indexing in the newly generated array, like this:

```
np.true_divide(arr.cumsum(axis=0)[bot_ix-1,range(arr.shape[1])], bot_ix)
```

I won't make any assumptions about speed, as it is needlessly computing the cumulative sum for more elements than strictly required, but it depends entirely on your particular data.

Answer (score 0):

A blend of Divakar and Oliver W.

```
mask = np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:, None] < bot_ix
(arr * mask).sum(0) / bot_ix.astype(float)

array([ 5. ,  3.5,  4.5,  3. ,  6.5])
```